# Symplectic basis $(A_i,B_i)$ such that $S= $ span$(A_1,B_1,...,A_k,B_k)$ for some $k$ when $S$ is symplectic

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic vector space of dimension $2n$. How can I show that for a symplectic subspace $S \subset V$, there exists a symplectic basis $(A_i,B_i)$ such that $S= $ span$(A_1,B_1,...,A_k,B_k)$ for some $k$.

I know that since $S$ is symplectic, $S \cap S^\perp= \lbrace0 \rbrace$ and this is true iff $\omega|_S$ is nondegenerate. Let $(\alpha^1, \beta^1,...,\alpha^n, \beta^n)$ be the corresponding dual basis for $V^\ast$. Then $\omega$ is defined by $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^i \wedge \beta^i$. I do not know how to continue.

Comment: It's related to this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95273/symplectic-basis-a-i-b-i-such-that-s-spana-1-a-k-for-some-k-wh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S is a symplectic space so it has a symplectic basis. Its orthogonal subspace is also a symplectic space, so it has a symplectic base. Now consider the union of these two bases.

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: I don't know what to add, really. You know that every symplectic space has a symplectic basis: Since S and $S^\perp$ are symplectic spaces, they have symplectic bases; now consider the union of these two bases: it is obviously a basis of the whole space, and you have to check that it is a symplectic basis. What part do you want details on?

Comment: Just to see the distinction between them, what happens if $S$ is not symplectic but isotropic?

Comment: In that case S does not have a symplectic basis, nor is it linearly disjoint from its orthogonal complement, so we cannot even start the construction.